# Error running file with parenthesis in name

Tags: c++, windows, file, oop

i was writing some code related to OOP and saved the file as "polymorphism(PureVirtualFunctions)" and since then the terminal showed me the following error

[PureVirtualFunctions : The term 'PureVirtualFunctions' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

- ... e\CPP\new" ; if ($?) { g++ polymorphism(PureVirtualFunctions).cpp -o]

but as soon as i saved it as "polymorphism_PureVirtualFunctions, the problem was solved.
Now i want to know the reason for the error i got with the earlier name, Thanks.

i tried saving it with a different name without the parenthesis and it worked!
For reference, i was coding in VSCODE in Windows10

Comment: You'll need to escape the brackets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: This is a feature of Windows (and other operating systems), and has nothing to do with your compiler or with C++.